# Zoom to domain with intervals

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'm using d3 to build a chart with data I get from a mysql database. I was working with this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/431a331294d2b5ddd33f947cf4c81319. You can see my code in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HvypuHsrqPSDIcEOiFS0.

I would like that my chart show me the last 8 hours when the chart is load, and then, be able to make zoom or move the chart. I was working in this piece of code:

```
  var d0 = new Date(2003, 1, 5),
  d1 = new Date(2003, 2, 10);
```

I was working for d1 show the actual date, and d0 8 hours less, with one idea from a question in stackoverflow:

```
var d = new Date(); 
var d0 = d3.time.hour.offset(d, -8);
var d1 = new Date();
```

But the chart keep freezed, without transition or zoom capacity. I think is a problem about time format (I got this data: {"Time":"2017-03-12 22:40:23","Probe1":"20.10"}). I was looking for information about intervals, zoom behaviour or offset features, but I can't find a solution. Any idea?

Thanks!

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved a few days later, with this:

```
var d0 = new Date(Date.now() - duration);  

var d1 = new Date(Date.now());
```

Alex.